# Compile Error Changing Backend System of Thrust with CUDA 5

Tags: cuda, thrust

I installed CUDA 5 recently and found existing code based on Thrust cannot be compiled. The error only happens if I switch to OMP or TBB.

So I did an experiment using monte_carlo.cpp from Thrust example.

When I using include path of CUDA 5.0, I got this error:

> g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp
>   -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -fopenmp -I /usr/local/cuda-5.0/include/
>
> /tmp/ccFsJtAs.o: In function `main': monte_carlo.cpp:(.text+0xa0):
>   undefined reference to`float
>   thrust::detail::backend::cuda::reduce_n, float,
>   thrust::use_default>, long, float, thrust::plus
>
> > (thrust::transform_iterator, float,
> >     thrust::use_default>, long, float, thrust::plus)'

But if I change to CUDA 4.1 using

> g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp
>   -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -fopenmp -I /usr/local/cuda-4.1/include/

There is no error.

And my platform is Ubuntu 10.04 with g++ 4.4.3.

Hope anyone can help me, thanks!

**Edit**
OMP problem is solved by changing the order of `-fopenmp` as @Robert pointed out, but I failed to compile using TBB

> g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_TBB -ltbb -I /usr/local/cuda/include/
>   /tmp/ccxSmcnJ.o: In function `main':
>   monte_carlo.cpp:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to`float thrust::detail::backend::cuda::reduce_n, float, thrust::use_default>, long, float, thrust::plus >(thrust::transform_iterator, float, thrust::use_default>, long, float, thrust::plus)'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

But the compilation successes if I use

> g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_TBB -ltbb -I /usr/local/cuda-4.1/include/

Comment: In cuda 4.1, your compile command fails for me, but if I match the instructions [here](http://wiki.thrust.googlecode.com/hg-history/f80897f84942afe49e386b9ed63df328085193cb/DeviceBackends.wiki) using: `g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp -fopenmp -DTHRUST_DEVICE_BACKEND=THRUST_DEVICE_BACKEND_OMP -lgomp -I\usr\local\cuda\include` it works.  In my case the order of the compiler switches matters.  In CUDA 5.0 I observe the same behavior.  Is there some reason you're not matching the order of the compiler switches exactly as given in the instructions? (you're also not including `-lgomp` ?)

Comment: @RobertCrovella I added -lgomp but got same error

Comment: The order of the switches matters (e.g. `-fopenmp`).  The order that works for me is different than what you posted.  What you posted also doesn't match the instructions.

Comment: Try the command exactly like this:  `g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp -fopenmp -DTHRUST_DEVICE_BACKEND=THRUST_DEVICE_BACKEND_OMP -lgomp -I/usr/local/cuda-5.0/include`

Comment: Thanks  @RobertCrovella OMP now is compiled but I tried TBB it failed. I used g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_TBB -ltbb -I /usr/local/cuda/include/

Comment: have you installed tbb on your machine?

Comment: The version of Thrust which ships with CUDA 5 (1.5.3) does not implement a TBB backend.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenMP compilation would appear to have been caused by incorrectly specified compilation arguments. Compiling using

```
g++ -O2 -o monte_carlo monte_carlo.cpp -fopenmp -DTHRUST_DEVICE_BACKEND=THRUST_DEVICE_BACKEND_OMP -lgomp -I\usr\local\cuda\include
```

(i.e. specifying OpenMP code generation before any pre-processor directives) allowed for correct compilation using the thrust OpenMP backed.

The reported TBB back end compilation error would appear to have been caused by attempting to use the TBB backend on thrust 1.5.3, which has no TBB support.

[This answer has been assembled from question edits and comments to get the question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag]